# Cannot access JAR Manifest Specification page in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to make a Jar file in Eclipse, I go to export, select the folders and give it a directory and name, I click Next and I'm taken to the JAR Packaging Options but in there the Next button is greyed out and I cannot access the Jar Manifest Specification page. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error (red marks), for JAR Manifest Specifications Page the correct way is to go through the wizard, and click NEXT on the JAR Packaging options.